# Header not working as intended

Tags: php

I got a page and as it says in the code I want to redirect all users to Google when the current time is greater than the opening time.

This is something that I want to be done on all my pages, so I put the PHP tag in the header which has all the header settings (stylesheet for instance)

```
$openingtime = 1264256278;
if(!$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] < $openingtime){
   header('www.google.dk');
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't work at all.

I have no idea why this is a problem.

I have tried to echo out a string to see if the if sentence did work, and it does. I've used the header tag a few times before, and this hasn't been a problem before.

Comment: You mentioned you include this with your stylesheets? If there is any output (plain-text, HTML, CSS, etc.) prior to the `header()` call, then it will not work. Also, it's `header('Location: http://url');`

Comment: `header('Location: www.google.dk');` probably replace your header with this..

Comment: `when the current time is greater than the opening time.` - well your code says **less** than. And you forgot `Location:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `Location:` in the beginning of the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me it's either one (or both...) of these two problems:

- The headers have already been sent. That happens when there was output to the browser before your `header` statement
- The syntax is wrong, it should be something like `header('Location: http://www.google.dk')`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong ::
missing 'Location'

header('Location: http://www.google.dk');

Comment: This solution has already been covered in the other answers. Why did you post a new one? Also, your answer doesn't include the locaiton's protocol (eg `http:`).